# Detaching Pages from the Site Defintion

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am creating a template .aspx page  for use on a SharePoint site. I need to include my own CSS reference and jquery reference in the head of the page.

SPD only allows this when I edit the page in advanced mode, this gives me a warning stating it will detatch it from the site definition.

Is this the only way in which I can include these references to my CSS file and jquery. The CSS is only relevant to this template I've created so I don't want it in the master page template.

If I do this will it cause problems later down the line if a change is made to the master page? Will my page not receive those changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a content editor web part to the page and paste your css in a style tag and the scripts in a script tag